# How to extract nodes at regular interval using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, kml, extract, nodes

How can I extract nodes at a regular interval say 20 m from a path kml file having point located at random interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use random point along line tool

- distance is defined on map unit :

[image]

- then get values from your path with join by location tool 
  [image]